# CodeSynthesis XSD: Unresolved externals from Xerces

Tags: compiler-errors, xsd, symbols, xerces, codesynthesis

just after fixing a big error, the next errors occur

this time i have 39 unresolved externals, and how it looks its something from Xerces, but after an hour couldnt figure out what. also downloaded it new and added it to the project-properties

situation: i've generated Cpp-file out of a `XSD-scheme` over the `CodeSynthesis XSD`. now i wanted to test the scheme in **Visual Studio 10 with a console-application(QT5)**.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static char const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale" (__imp_?fgXercescDefaultLocale@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QBDB)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager * xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager" (__imp_?fgMemoryManager@XMLPlatformUtils@xercesc_3_1@@2PAVMemoryManager@2@A)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static wchar_t const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMComments" (__imp_?fgDOMComments@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QB_WB)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static wchar_t const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMDatatypeNormalization" (__imp_?fgDOMDatatypeNormalization@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QB_WB)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static wchar_t const * const xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgDOMElementContentWhitespace" (__imp_?fgDOMElementContentWhitespace@XMLUni@xercesc_3_1@@2QB_WB)
```

that are **5 out of the 39 errors**, i guess it wouldnt help much if i post the **34** others

could it be that i've generated the `cxx / hxx` the wrong way?:

`xsd cxx-tree $filepath$`

Comment: It seems you haven't linked your program to the Xerces-c library. Sorry, I don't know anything about Visual Studio 10

Comment: i have linked it over the VC++-direcotries (bin/lib/include) and the .lib in the additional dependencies. When i also link the xerces-dll, the unresolved symbols will disappear, but i just cant compile it because of "LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2F0". on google you only read that you should link the .lib instead of .dll, but then i get the unresolved errors...

Comment: One more tip: According to the [Xerces-C documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html) you will need to compile your application with the XERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY preprocessor macro defined if you use the Xerces-C static library (.lib)